# How to auto populate a property within a List property of a Class

Tags: c#, accessor, class-properties

Firstly, thanks in advance for anyone who can help.

I have a header and lines scenario.  I want the lines object to auto-populate with the headerId from the Header.  Please can someone help?

```
public class Header
{
    public int headerId { get; set; }
    public List<Lines> lines { get; set; }
}

public class Lines
{
    public int lineId { get; set; }
    public int headerId { get; set; }   //<<< want to autopopulate this from Header object
}
```

Comment: what version of visual studio are you using?

Comment: Hi Matt, VS2015

Comment: Where are you initializing the `Header` class and the list?

Comment: you don't really have a good option based on your design

Comment: I tried creating a constructor on the Lines object to set headerId somehow, but that didn't really work out.

Comment: You may want to rethink your design choice on this. Ideally, since your `Header` class already contains `headerId`, then there is no reason to propagate that variable down to every Lines object in that list since it's already associated with the parent class of `Header`.

Comment: Thanks Aman, it's so I could just access the lines list property and get back a list of all the lines in one go and pass straight into a DataTable.  I have a workaround, just wondering if there was an easy way of populating it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a number of ways you can do this.

## Option 1 - Fix on collection set.

```
public class Header
{
    private List<Lines> _lines
    public int HeaderId { get; set; }
    public List<Line> Lines 
    { 
        get { return _lines; }
        set 
        { 
            _lines = value;
            if(_lines != null)
            {
                foreach(var line in _lines)
                    line.HeaderId = HeaderId;
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Line
{
    public int LineId { get; set; }
    public int HeaderId { get; set; }  
}
```

The problem with this route is that the HeaderId is only set when you set `Lines` collection. That means you can change it after the fact or any new items you add to `Lines` will not be corrected.

## Option 2 - Pass in the Header when constructing the Line

```
public class Header
{

    public int HeaderId { get; set; }
    public List<Line> Lines { get; set; }
}

public class Line
{
    public Header ParentHeader { get; }
    public int LineId { get; set; }
    public int? HeaderId { get { return ParentHeader?.HeaderId; }  

    public Line(Header header)
    {
        ParentHeader = header;
    }
}
```

As long as you have the same `Header` instance for all of the lines, if you were change the `Header.HeaderId` all of the lines will automatically be updated.

## Option 3 - Don't add an instance of Line directly to the collection

```
public class Header
{
    List<Line> _lines = new List<Line>();

    public int HeaderId { get; set; }
    public ReadOnlyCollection<Line> Lines { get {return _lines.AsReadOnly(); }


    public void AddLine(Line line)
    {               
        line.HeaderId = HeaderId;
        _lines.Add(line);
    }
}
```

This will have the same issue as Option 1.

Comment: On Option 1 if you copy your `Lines_set()` logic to the `HeaderId_set()` function then you can keep the Lines.HeaderID in sync with the Header.HeaderID.  (one-way sync from Header to Line)

Comment: Sam Axe, thanks for your reply also, I'll try that out too.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this...

```
public class Header
{
    static int _headerIdSeed = 0;

    public int HeaderId { get; internal set; } = _headerIdSeed++;
    public IList<Line> Lines { get; } = new List<Line>();

    public Header Add(Line line)
    {
        line.HeaderId = this.HeaderId;
        this.Lines.Add(line);
        return this;
    }

    public Header Add(params Line[] lines)
    {
        return this.AddRange(lines);
    }

    public Header AddRange(IEnumerable<Line> lines)
    {
        foreach (var line in lines)
        {
            line.HeaderId = this.HeaderId;
            this.Lines.Add(line);
        }
        return this;
    }
}

public class Line
{
    static int _lineIdSeed = 0;
    public int LineId { get; internal set; } = _lineIdSeed++;
    public int HeaderId { get; internal set; }
}
```

... and you can use it like this ...

```
var header = new Header
{
    HeaderId = 1,
}.Add(new Line { },
      new Line { },
      new Line { });

foreach (var line in header.Lines)
    Console.WriteLine($"{line.HeaderId}-{line.LineId}");
/*
1-0
1-1
1-2
*/
```